# jQuery datePicker can't get val()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm puzzled by the jQuery UI datepicker. I have the following function:

```
$(".text-date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
}); 

$("#regdatum input").change(function() {
    alert('Regdatum from: '+$("#filter-regdatum-from-value").val());
    alert('Regdatum to: '+$("#filter-regdatum-to-value").val());        
    if (($("#filter-regdatum-from-value").attr("value") != '') && ($("#filter-regdatum-to-value").attr("value") != ''))
    {
        generateDomainList();       
    }
});
```

Which attaches the click event to the input fields within a div `#regdatum`. The two alerts shown here return the date chosen in the input field through datepicker. When the two fields have a value it needs to execute function `generateDomainList()`. In this function I try to get the values of the same input fields using the method above:

```
$("#filter-regdatum-from-value").val()
```

But no matter what I do at this point it will return 'undefined' (not as a string) in my alert. It doesn't seem logical to me, can anyone tell me why this occurs and perhaps how to work around it?

Comment: Can you include the HTML source for your `regdatum` inputs as well?  It appears that your selector syntax is incorrect for obtaining `val()`

Comment: curious why are you using .attr("value") instead of .val() in your if statement

Comment: Ok, sloppy. It's a remnant of testing. Found out that both give the same result.

Comment: HTML source of the input's (got 4 of em all different ID's same class that invokes the datepicker) <input type="text" id="filter-regdatum-from-value" name="filter-regdatum-from-value" class="text-date" value="" />

Comment: @tvgemert: Hmm. :( The code works for me.  I get the values properly through the `alert(), not `undefined`.

Comment: Adam, that's completely true! But the point is that the same line of code returns 'undefined' when executed from within the function generateDomainList();

Comment: can you assign the value to a variable before the alerts and then use the variable in both places?  Not saying it'll fix it, just something to try

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at full code it is difficult to find the issue. But it may be caused by variable access level within a function. Try following modification it may work.

```
var from_val="";
var to_val="";

$("#regdatum input").change(function() {
    from_val=$("#filter-regdatum-from-value").val();
    to_val=$("#filter-regdatum-to-value").val();        
    if ((from_val != undefined) && (to_val != undefined))
    {
        generateDomainList();       
    }
});

function generateDomainList()
{
   alert(from_val);
   alert(to_val);
}
```

Here note that variable declare before the event handler important.

Or there may be another reason that two instance of same `id` selector.